# How to add a filter name to cloudWatchLog using the serverless framework?

Tags: serverless-framework

The cloudWatch filter name picks it by its random name on the deployment.

cloudwatchLog:
logGroup: ‘/aws/lambda/hello-world’
filterName: ‘hello-world’
cloudwatchLog:
logGroup: ‘/aws/lambda/hello-world-python’
filterName: ‘hello-world-python’

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM4KC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr4ml.png)